# _$UserSerializerMixin do I need it?

Tags: serialization, dart, flutter

I was struggling with serializations when I found this guide
https://flutter.io/json/
In it I found:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User extends Object with _$UserSerializerMixin{
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}
```

I followed the guide (also run the flutter packages pub run build_runner watch command) and everything is good except for  `_$UserSerializerMixin`. It says: classes can only mixin other classes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `_$UserSerializerMixin`class isn't in the built user.g.dart.

The example at https://flutter.io/json/#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries is old and only runs using package versions shown in the example pubspec.yaml on that page.

If you use latest packages, see example here instead: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/json_serializable/latest/

Note that one no longer needs to extend their class with `_$UserSerializerMixin`. with v1.x of the packages, `_$UserToJson` is created instead. Changes to your class are now simpler.

(I struggled for quite a while myself as I had used latest package versions in pubspec.yaml but the old example.)